# Oracle MAF : TypeError: Object[object Object] has no method 'signature'

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, oracle-maf

I am developing the mobile application using Oracle MAF. In that application I need to implement the Signature capture functionality.

For that I have downloaded the [Signature Capture Demo app from this link](https://blogs.oracle.com/mobile/entry/signature_capture_demo).

And trying to integrate with my application. I did all the necessary settings mentioned in that link.
But after running the application I am getting following error

> TypeError: Object[object Object] has no method 'signature'

The Piece of code as follows

```
<![CDATA[
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        (function()
                        {
                            makeSig = function() {
                              try
                              {
                                var sigElement = document.getElementById("sig");
                                if (sigElement == null)
                                  alert("sigElement not found");
                                var sigJq = $(sigElement);
                                sigJq.signature();
                                sigJq.signature({guideline: true});
                              }
                              catch (problem)
                              {
                                alert("Problem with verbatim code: " + problem);
                              }
                            }
                            window.setTimeout(makeSig, 250);
                        })();
                        </script>
                        <div id="sig" style="height:200px;width:99%"></div>
                        ]]>
```

Please let me know why it is not able to find the signature method. I have also included all the required `.js` files in the project.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: First try to understand how jQuery selector works. This link will help you to understand. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are properly including the library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.signature.js"></script>
```

then try something like this

```
var sigJq = $("sig");
sigJq.signature();
```

Comment: Thanks for such quick resonse Liam Schauerman. I have tried with both the above tricks. For the second option I am getting the same exception but for the 1st one it says #<HTMLDivElement>has no method 'signature'.

Comment: Please suggest any resolution guys..Thanks

Comment: Hi Liam,I am using the thirdparty plugin provided by keith wood. you can find the plugin here : http://keith-wood.name/signature.html

Comment: And you are using the js file like his example?    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.signature.js"></script>

Comment: No. In oracle MAF we have to add the required files in the Content section of each page. So I have added all the files there so now I dont need to add it explicitly.

Comment: I am trying to integrate signature capture application in My mobile application. When I run the signature capture application standalone it runs fine with the above code but when I integrate it with my code, it is throwing the exception.

Comment: Hi, It seems like jquery.signature.js and other .js files are not getting loaded at the runtime. Can anyone tell me how should I include those file in the above code? Thanks